# Symfony custom constraint / Validation Birthday

Tags: validation, symfony, constraints

i've written a custom validation for a birthday field type.
I've already written custom validation before, but not for a DateTime field.

The validate function of my AdultBirthdateValidator is the following:

```
// $value of type DateTime
public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
{
    $min_age = 18;

    if($this->validate_age($value, $min_age) === false)
    {
        $this->context->buildViolation($constraint->message)
            ->setParameter('%string%', $value)
            ->addViolation();
    }
}
```

The problem is, that i don't exactly now what:

```
->setParameter('%string%', $value)
```

this function expects. The passed $value is a DateTime field, so i dont know how to pass it here. (String is of course throwing an error).
How should i do this correctly?

Regards.

Comment: What format are you sending the DateTime in?  Can you post an example of the data being sent to the server.

Comment: You can capture this by using chrome developer tools, and intercepting the network traffic.  You are looking for the form data, it may be under headers

Comment: For dates using a library helps, like this one https://github.com/Lawondyss/MomentPHP

Comment: This is the format $value has:
object(DateTime)#1310 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "1940-01-01 00:00:00.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(13) "Europe/Berlin"
}

The validation is working (if is 18+ or not), just passing that error to the violation list isn't. (Because i don't know how to use setParameter() for a DateTime object) Regards

Comment: To clarify, your validation is working but the issue is with handling an error (invalid date)?

Comment: Have you thoroughly read this: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/datetime.html

Comment: I know the DateTime field.. i just don't know how to pass the validation back to Symfony that the error gets rendered in the form of the view.. For example if $value would have been a string that i checked, ->setParameter() would not have caused an error and the field error would have been just automatically rendered in the view. But because $value is not a string, it is a datetime, i don't know how to handle the "send the error back to the view" point.

Comment: So, you are wanting to provide the user with a clear error message, letting them know that they are not old enough to user the site (18+)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64573/discussion-between-dan-green-and-nova-cp).

Comment: Anyone else an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

From what I read, you should be able to do something like this...

```
$this->context->addViolation(
    $constraint->message,
    array('%string%' => $value->format('Y-m-d')) //Formats DateTime to a string
);
```

But what I haven't seen is your corresponding class with the `$constraint->message`, so I'm not sure if that's the format you want, or really if you even need their birthdate to generate the constraint message.

Comment: hey, so this is not working i already tried:
if($this->validate_age($value, $min_age) === false)
        {
            $this->context->buildViolation($constraint->message)
                ->setParameter('%string%', $value->format('dd/MM/yyyy'))
                ->addViolation();
        }

(buildValidation symfony 2.5).

My other class is the following:

 */
class AdultBirthdate extends Constraint
{
    public $message = 'profile.register.adultBirthdate';

    public function validatedBy()
    {
        return get_class($this).'Validator';
    }
}

Comment: I don't know why, there are no errors thrown but the violation is never added.. when i call $err = (string) $this->form->getErrors(true, false); later, it is not in here. All other errors but my custom constraint isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. Problem was the $value->format('Y-m-d') and a mistake in my Serializer function.